# How to use aria-labelledby to enable accessibility?

Tags: html, css, background-image, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a CSS class that has a background image

e.g. :

```
.my_class_bg_image { 
    background: url(myPhoto.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

I want to make the page that contains this CSS class accessible.

Can I use this ?:

```
<span role="img" aria-labelledby="ddd" title="This is my bg image title" class="my_class_bg_image">
  <span id="ddd">This is my text which is shown when the image cannot be loaded, 
     but it's also there and invisible and when the image load succeeds
  </span>
</span>
```

If not, how can I make such html elements accessible ?
 - html elements which contain CSS classes that contain a bg image

Comment: What about using jQuery?

Comment: @ArunCM , What do you mean ? - Can you be more specific ?

Comment: If your span has specified class show it otherwise hide it by using css. You can check this link http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-check-if-an-element-has-a-certain-class-name-with-jquery/

Comment: Do not use jQuery. You aren't even solving the problem, @ArunCM, you are just tossing out a technology. If OP takes that route then OP will be worse than when he/she started.

Answer (score 2):

Using `aria-labelledby` with an ID will make the text available to screen readers that need it. If you want to visibly hide some content I'd recommend using the method that [Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/tenydnblog/clip-hidden-content-better-accessibility-53456.html) came up with. Once you add the CSS to your stylesheet you'll just need to add a class (in this case `sr-only`) to your HTML to visibly hide the text.

The code would be:

```
.sr-only {
   height: 1px;
   width: 1px;
   clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
}
```

This clips the content out (`clip`), hides any overflow, and for browsers that don't render `clip` the 'correct' way, positions them absolutely so they come out of the overall layout flow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to address accessibility (and your audience is only using left-to-right languages), then you can use `text-indent` to visually hide the text but allow it to still be read by screen readers.

This technique works best on block-level elements. I suspect your example would not use `span`s and use a background photo, though if you are using a sprite icon then you would change this a bit.

```
.my_class_bg_image {
  display: block; /* if you are not using a block-level element */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -999px;
}
```

[I made a quick CodePen](http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/vKZVJW?editors=1100).

Comment: I want to clarify that my technique works well. My question is : Is it good for accessibility ?  or in other words : Can the text ("This is my text which is shown....") be read by screen readers ?

Comment: Yes, a screen reader will read the `aria-labelledby` (however, your code example reads it twice). If you want to visually hide the text you will need to be careful how you do it else you may lose it for screen readers. In short, your code example is not complete enough to say it will work when deployed. That is why I offered the code sample and CodePen.